# Why methods' names are so long in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I've learned C/C++, Python, Matlab and many other language, but I was really surprised by the long method name in objective-c.

What's the advantage of using long name?
Why no other language use long name?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any language can use long names to make it clear what variables / methods are for. In Obj-C it's a convention, but that's all. You can still write Obj-C with rubbish names if you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is something like code convention. Usually it is very useful.

But you can name your methods as you want. Also notice that it is not strongly required to name all parameters. For example you can create method

```
- (void)makeDateFromDay:(int)day month:(int)month year:(int)year
```

and call this way

```
[someObject makeDateFromDay:18 month:2 year:2014];
```

but you also can name it shorter

```
- (void)makeDateFrom:(int)day :(int)month :(int)year
```

and call like this

```
[someObject makeDateFrom:18:2:2014];
```

But it is not so readable, yes?

Comment: Is there any similar situation in other languages?

Comment: @Mr.DMS Do you have `MakeDateFromDayMonthYear()` in $language? That wouldn't be shorter. And it would be useless because you have to count parameters and relate it to the name. `MakeDateFromMonthYearHourMinuteDoubleSecond()` has 6 or 7 parameters? Because leading parameter names are close to be useless some programming languages simply does not use it and you have to keep it in mind. Instead you have overloading, a self-descriptive, easy to use technology you do not have to remember anything. ;-) When you read Objective-C code with descriptive parameters you almost always know, what's going on

Answer (score 4):

The plain answer is that the long method names are self-descriptive. (And since each argument is introduced through another method name part, the method name gets even longer.) The advantage is that the code reads really easily, and thanks to code completion there is no extra penalty for typing the whole thing by hand.

Comment: I'd like to add to that that you don't have to suffer the same things you do when reading C language .h header files with no proper documentation and method names like void * my_method(int a, int b, void *ctx, sothx t)

Answer (score 0):

Obj-C method names closely respect a convention with more rules than other languages. For example the last word of the method name is the name of the first argument.

```
- (id)valueForRow:(int)row Column:(int)column
```

In C++ this would probably be:

```
void getValue(int row, int column)
```

Comment: According to Apple's documented conventions, that method signature ought to be as follows: `- (id)valueForRow:(int)row column:(int)column`. Methods that return a value should begin with a noun or noun phrase describing the return value, so you shouldn't prefix them with a verb such as `get`.

Answer (score 0):

More methods are longer, more they speak themselves.
If you consider delegate method, in the method there is also the references
to class from the method being called because it can be very userfull to make some
kind of operation on class that conforms to protocol.

If you suppose to have an app where you have to do a lot of calc, like a shop application,
you can't declare all methods with the same name (for example sum) because when you have more than two methods with the same name you start to lose control on your code.

A lot of programmers using short syntax like name vars as:
a, b
 
But when you open code some months later you have to reconstruct the logic of program to know what a certain var does.

Give a long name to methods can be also usefull when you work in team to be more safe on method name replication.